# R: failed installation Slidify - Error: Command failed (1) not recognized as a i/e command

Tags: r, windows-8, rstudio, slidify

I'm trying to install slidify but it returns an error. 
I suppose it's caused to the directory name.

```
> library(devtools)
> install_github('slidify', 'ramnathv')
Installing github repo(s) slidify/master from ramnathv
Downloading slidify.zip from https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\matte_000\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkfDfkx/slidify.zip
Installing slidify
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.1/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
"C:\Users\matte_000\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkfDfkx\slidify-master"  \
--library="C:/Users/matte_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.0" --with-keep.source -- install-tests 

"C:\Program" 'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
 Error: Command failed (1)

> install_github('slidifyLibraries', 'ramnathv')
Installing github repo(s) slidifyLibraries/master from ramnathv
Downloading slidifyLibraries.zip from https://github.com/ramnathv/slidifyLibraries/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\matte_000\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkfDfkx/slidifyLibraries.zip
Installing slidifyLibraries
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.1/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
"C:\Users\matte_000\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpkfDfkx\slidifyLibraries-master"  \
--library="C:/Users/matte_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.0" --with-keep.source --install-tests 

"C:\Program" 'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I'm new at R and I tried even the following code to install it manually:

```
> pkgs = c("slidify","slidifyLibraries")
> install.packages(pkgs,lib="C:/Users/matte_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.0","https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/archive/master.zip", repos = NULL)
Warning in install.packages :
packages ‘slidify’, ‘slidifyLibraries’ are not available (for R version 3.0.1)
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
unable to access index for repository https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/archive/master.zip
Warning in install.packages :
packages ‘slidify’, ‘slidifyLibraries’ are not available (for R version 3.0.1)
```

Finally if it helps I post the result of sessionInfo(), running on Windows 8 x64:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Italy.1252  LC_CTYPE=Italian_Italy.1252 LC_MONETARY=Italian_Italy.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Italian_Italy.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.4 httr_0.2       memoise_0.1    parallel_3.0.1 RCurl_1.95-4.1 stringr_0.6.2 
[8] tools_3.0.1    whisker_0.3-2
```

Do you have any idea to fix it?
I google it but didn't find anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

try this method, Install slidifyLibraries from Windows command prompt

http://thiagosilva.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/installing-slidify-on-a-windows-machine/